# my javascript array is showing 'undefined' after applying a sort function to it. please assist

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do my first ever leetcode challenge. I am failing terribly. I just don't get why my array is showing as undefined here. I am just trying to sort it.

I know there are other ways to sort arrays, but I just can't seem to understand why my sort method here isn't working. i would really appreciate an explanation.

edit: i managed to solve the undefined issue, but now it seems like the array is only storing one single value. is there anything obvious i am doing wrong here?

edit 2: i think the array was only storing 1 single value because I am using 'reduce' here, and thats just the nature of using reduce it seems like. i will try again. thanks for your help guys :)

```
'use strict';


// define variables
let indexarray, outputarray = [];
const arr1 = [9, 4, 9, 8, 4];
const arr2 = [4, 9, 5];

function arrsort(array) {
  const outputz = array.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b });
  return outputz;
};


// sort arrays
let arr1s = arrsort(arr1);
let arr2s = arrsort(arr2);

// foreach in arr1, go through arr2 and check if current arr1 array value matches. if yes and current arr2 index val isnt present in 'indexarray', then add current arr2 array val to array 'outputarray' and current index val to 'indexarray'.

arr1s.forEach(function (x, i) {

  arr2s.reduce(function (pval, cval, ival) {
    if (cval === x && !indexarray.includes(ival)) {
      indexarray.push(ival);
      outputarray.push(cval);
    };
  });

});
```

**Updated - final solution shown below was submitted ~noobhuzi**

```js
 const intersect = function (nums1, nums2) {

  // define variables
  let indexarray1 = [];
  let indexarray2 = [];
  let outputarray = [];

  const arrsort = function (array) {
    return array.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b });
  };


  // sort arrays && 
  let nums1s = arrsort(nums1);
  let nums2s = arrsort(nums2);

  /* foreach in nums1, go through nums2, check if nums1 val (x) matches nums2 val (pval). if yes and current nums2 index val isnt present in 'indexarray', then add current nums2 array val to array 'outputarray' and current index val to 'indexarray'. */

  if (1 <= nums1s.length) {
    nums1s.forEach(function (x, i) {
      if (nums2s.length <= 1000 && 0 <= x && x <= 1000 && typeof x === "number") {
        nums2s.forEach(function (pval, iv) {
          if (pval === x && !indexarray2.includes(iv) && !indexarray1.includes(i)) {
            indexarray1.push(i);
            indexarray2.push(iv);
            outputarray.push(pval);
          }
        });
      } else {
        console.log("ERROR: some constraint is stopping the code from continuing. please check around ForEach.");
      };
    });

  } else {
    console.log("ERROR: nums1s constraint is stopping the code from continuing as its length is less than 1.");
  };

  console.log("outputarray: " + outputarray);
  return outputarray;

};
```

Comment: your function `arrsort` is not returning anything ... thus `arr1s` and `arr2s` are undefined

Comment: _"The [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method sorts the elements of an array **in place** and returns the sorted array."_ - `arr1` and `arr2` will be modified/sorted after you call `.sort()` on them. Returning something from `arrsort` is therefor not necessary. Just use `arr1`/`arr2` directly.

Comment: Your usage of [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is not how that function is supposed to be used. Re-read the documentation for that method.

Comment: thanks guys - i will try again without using 'reduce'. <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sort function have to return the sorted array. Also the initialization of `indexarray` is also wrong.

Also you are making use of `Array.reduce` incorrectly. You just need to have `Array.forEach`

**Updated answer.**

```js
// define variables
let indexarray = [];
let outputarray = [];
const arr1 = [9, 4, 9, 8, 4];
const arr2 = [4, 9, 5];

function arrsort(array) {
  return array.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b });
};


// sort arrays
let arr1s = arrsort(arr1);
let arr2s = arrsort(arr2);

// foreach in arr1, go through arr2 and check if current arr1 array value matches.
// if yes and current arr2 index val isnt present in 'indexarray',
// then add current arr2 array val to array 'outputarray' and current index val to 'indexarray'.
arr1s.forEach(function (x, i) {
  arr2s.forEach(function (pval, i2) {
    if (pval === x && !indexarray.includes(i2)) {
      indexarray.push(i2);
      outputarray.push(pval);
    };
  });
});

console.log(indexarray);
console.log(outputarray);
```

Comment: thanks guys! yeah it seems like reduce is completely the wrong thing for me to have used. i will try again. appreciate your help :)

Comment: thanks for the update aswell! its much appreciated!